# Visual Studio 2017 Docker Edit and Continue Razor Pages

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Edit and Continue not updating when a change is made on the host filesystem, but it does work changing it inside the running container.

**update 8th Aug 2018** Workaround is working and fix aiming to get into ASP.NET Core 2.2

**update 7th Aug 2018** Workaround nearly found: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8173

**update 25th July 2018** This is only affecting Razor Pages. MVC works as expected

**update 26th July 2018** Steps to repro for working MVC:

- dotnet new mvc
- docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -v %cd%:/app/ -w /app/aspnetapp microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk dotnet watch run --no-launch-profile

Not working razor pages

- dotnet new razor
- docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -v %cd%:/app/ -w /app microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk dotnet watch run --no-launch-profile

**end update**

From [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1#edit-and-continue)

> Changes to static files and Razor views are automatically updated
>   without the need for a compilation step

Steps to repro:

- .NET Core SDK 2.1.302
- VS2017 15.7.5, File, New Project, ASP.NET Core Web Application, ASP.NET Core 2.1, Web Application, Enable Docker Support, Ctrl F5 to run
- update the About.cshtml page

[image]

As shown the file hasn't reflected the update in the browser (I checked with curl - there is nothing cached)

If you go into the running container:

```
docker exec -it nameofcontainer /bin/bash
```

Then change the file directly in the volume mounted /app directory, it does work.

Everything works fine using Windows Containers.

I've tried 2 different base images to see if that helped:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base  (default 255MB)
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.2-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine3.7 AS base  (164MB)
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.2-aspnetcore-runtime-bionic AS base (281MB)
```

This made no difference.

Have checked on 3 different machines which are all Windows 10. Docker version is Community 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513). This is the stable Docker channel.

I'm assuming this is something to do with DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1 and the volume mounted filesystem. [Potential fix](https://github.com/Angelinsky7/Docker-Volume-Watcher)

Tried using [VS2017 preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) with the same behaviour.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, docker image **isn't rebuilt** when you start the project in Debug mode. The project is just complied and your local directory is linked within the Docker Container. Only when you do an release build, a new image is created so changing it within the container should result in exactly same behaviour as changing it outside. See the **blue marked** box in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1#debug)

Comment: Thanks @Tseng. I'm trying to get the file watch working so don't have to do a Ctrl F5 to see the effect of a .cshtml change.  [it should work I think](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1#edit-and-continue)

Comment: docker heavily uses caching to make it as quick as possible.. surely local development you should not be using the docker.. ? just run it locally, do the development and when done use the docker to run it? running docker with local development (constant updates) = nightmare

Comment: Is being investigated at the moment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8173